# Prove that $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \left( n - \frac 1 {e^{\frac 1 n} - 1} \right) = \frac 1 2$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

### Limit of reciprocal of nth root of e minus 1 is linear

I somehow got around to needing to know the value of $\frac 1 {e^{\frac 1 n}  -1}$, and noticed that it seems very linear:
[image: The function seems linear]
And that the difference from $n$ seems to go to $\frac 1 2$:
[image: Limit of difference is a half]
Thus I would like to see a proof of this fact, which I was unable to prove:
$$\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \left( n - \frac 1 {e^{\frac 1 n} - 1} \right) = \frac 1 2$$

Comment: Your formula makes no sense, the result of a $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}$ cannot depend on $N$. – Perhaps you want to show that the difference converges to zero? Or the quotient to one?

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, my bad! That's how I wrote it in the first place :)

Comment: Your title has the phrase "nth sqrt of". The "sqrt" means "_square_ root", so a root with specifically $N=2$. So I think what you mean to say is "nth root of".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \left( N - \frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{N}} -1} \right) = \lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{e^x -1}\right) = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^x - 1 -x}{x(e^x-1)}$$

Now apply L'Hospital's rule twice to get this being $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^x}{2e^x +xe^x} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{2+x} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Whoops, didn't see this post before I replied.  Couple comments that may be helpful for some learners: an arguably better way than L'Hopital's Rule to understand the limit is to use the Taylor series for $e^x$ (once you learn about that important tool).  Also, more importantly, the given equivalence should use the one-sided limit as $x \rightarrow 0^+$ (from the right), since $x = 1/N$ only takes positive values.

Answer (score 7):

$$e^{1/N}=1+\frac1N+\frac1{2N^2}+o(N^{-2})\\
e^{1/N}-1=\frac1N\left(1+\frac1{2N}+o(N^{-1})\right)\\
\frac1{e^{1/N}-1}=N\left(1+\frac1{2N}+o(N^{-1})\right)^{-1}\\
=N\left(1-\frac1{2N}+o(N^{-1})\right)$$

Comment: With the $o$-notation, those should be $=$ not $\approx$

Comment: That's fixed now

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \left( n - \frac 1 {e^{\frac 1 n} - 1} \right)=\lim \limits _{m \to 0} \left(\frac 1m - \frac 1 {e^m - 1} \right)=\lim \limits _{m \to 0}\frac{e^m-1-m}{m(e^m-1)}$$

Now from $e^m=1+m+\frac {m^2}{2!}+\frac{m^2}{3!}+o(m^3)$ we get 
$$\lim \limits _{m \to 0}\frac{e^m-1-m}{m(e^m-1)}=\lim \limits _{m \to 0}\frac{m^2(\frac12+\frac{m}{3!}+....)}{m^2(1+\frac m2+....)}=\lim \limits _{m \to 0}\frac{\frac12+\frac{m}{3!}+....}{1+\frac m2+....}=\frac12 $$